# How to select the time frame while navigating system trace in android profiling

Tags: android, profiling, systrace

I'm more interested in time frame where the traversal work is being done by the main thread, or in other words, I want to select any region in the thread section.
Not able to select that region.
Anyone knows about this?

[image: is done]

Answer (score 0):

Actually It worked, I just needed to restart the Android studio and select normally like we do any text selection from the trackPad or mouse.